# how to create a link to a JSF page from outside the application

Tags: jsf

I am working with a JSF application that posts on every mouse click, so if you get 5 pages deep, your url stays the same.

now i need to link to one of these pages from outside of jsf. what can i do?

(i am new to jsf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation rules use forward by default, that's why the URL does not change.

Use `http://site.com/ctx/page.jsf` to access a given page. `*.jsf` is the mapping of your faces servlet to in `web.xml` (it can have different value in your configuration, but normally it is `*.jsf` or `/faces/*`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if ive got it right but as much as i understood it you need to use GET instead of POST this time, right? 
in my current project we still use JSF 1.2 and that is achieved by PrettyFaces (http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) by us. do you mean that?

Comment: ive tried using get instead of post, but there is jsf state in the post that might change between logins

Comment: ok, maybe Bozho got it right :) i still dont get what you wanna achieve.